# Conditionally choose a data set in a SAS data step

Tags: macros, do-loops

I want to choose between 2 data sets based on a specific condition. What I thought was correct either goes to the wrong condition or I end up in an infinite loop. I want to do all of this within a macro and leave the loop when the condition is true.

```
%MACRO M;
%DO %UNTIL (ICU_LAST=FALSE);
    /* REMOVE ANY "LAST" RECORDS THAT ARE IN ICU AS THEY WILL NOT HAVE A LLOC ASSOCIATED WITH THEM */
    DATA LAST_TEST1;
        FALSE = 0;
        TRUE = 1;
        FORMAT SEEN 8.;
        RETAIN SEEN;
        RETAIN RECNO;
        IF SEEN=. THEN SEEN = FALSE;
        IF SEEN = FALSE THEN 
        DO;
            SET TESTTABLE_ENUMERATE END = LAST;
            SEEN = TRUE;
        END;
        ELSE
            SET RM_LAST_ICU END = LAST;
        IF LAST THEN
            ENDRECNO = 'LAST';
    RUN;

    /* IF THE LAST RECORD FOR EACH ACCOUNT IS AN ICU UNIT THEN DELETE IT AS THERE WILL BE NO ORDER OR ADMIT DATES ASSOCIATED WITH IT */
    DATA RM_LAST_ICU;
    FORMAT ICU_LAST 8.;
    IF ICU_LAST = . THEN ICU_LAST = FALSE;
    SET LAST_TEST1;
    IF LOCATIONNURSEUNITCODEDESC IN (&ICU_LIST.) AND ENDRECNO = 'LAST' THEN 
        DO;
            DELETE;
            ICU_LAST = TRUE;
        END;
    ELSE
        ICU_LAST = FALSE;
    RUN;

%END;
%MEND;
%M;
```

Comment: How do you want to convert your data values into macro variables so that your macro logic can test them?  Currently you have coded an infinite loop since a string that starts with an uppercase i can never equal a string that starts with an uppercase f.

Comment: Not sure what you mean Tom, where is the string that starts with 'I' and where do I set it equal to 'F'? In other words if I have looped through the macro once then use the first data set and seen gets set to true, and upon subsequent loops use the second data set

Comment: Part of the issue is that I am calling (setting) a data set that has not been created yet, i.e. RM_LAST_ICU so at runtime when it tries to process the code, it is looking for the data set RM_LAST_ICU which will not get created until the following data step.

Comment: I resolved my problem... I I created an empty table of the same name (RM_LAST_ICU) outside of the macro then I call the macro proc sql;
proc sql;
create table rm_last_icu 
(var1, var2,...var n);quit;

Comment: Your %DO loop will only stop when the seven character constant string  `ICU_TEST` is equal to the five character constant string  `FALSE`. Which can obviously never be true.